# SMTP Client 5.5.1 issue

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I have a simple web smtpclient application using C#.

```
//store server name
string ServerName = "smtp.gmail.com";

// Command line argument must the the SMTP host.
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ServerName);
// Specify the e-mail sender. 
// Create a mailing address that includes a UTF8 character 
// in the display name.
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Port = 587;
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("youremailid",
    "nameprefix " + (char)0xD8 + " namesuffix",
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
// Set destinations for the e-mail message.
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("receipentemailid");
// Specify the message content.
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Body = "This is a test e-mail message sent by an application. ";
// Include some non-ASCII characters in body and subject. 
string someArrows = new string(new char[] { '\u2190', '\u2191', '\u2192', '\u2193' });
message.Body += Environment.NewLine + someArrows;
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.Subject = "test message 1" + someArrows;
message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
// Set the method that is called back when the send operation ends.
client.SendCompleted += new
SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
// The userState can be any object that allows your callback  
// method to identify this send operation. 
// For this example, the userToken is a string constant. 
string userState = "test message1";
client.SendAsync(message, userState);
Console.WriteLine("Sending message... press c to cancel mail. Press any other key to exit.");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
// If the user canceled the send, and mail hasn't been sent yet, 
// then cancel the pending operation. 
if (answer.StartsWith("c") && mailSent == false)
{
    client.SendAsyncCancel();
}
// Clean up.
message.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
```

It's giving me:

> [testMessage1] System.Net.Mail.SmtpException:the SMTP server requires
>   a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.the server
>   response was: 5.5.1 Authentication required .

1)- Any way to get rid of this issue?

2)- is there any restriction to keep the receipent same domain server as sender?
    i.e. both should be either of gmail.com or yahoo.com

Comment: Do you need a username and password inorder to logon to the SMTP server?

Comment: How should i know this ? @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: Check the documentation from gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the credentials:

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: The server 'smtp.gmail.com' is already hardcoded and passed to 'SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ServerName)' im above code

Comment: I missed that. Are the credentials right? Also, did you place it after setting UseDefaultCredentials?

Comment: yes ,i used : 'client.UseDefaultCredentials=false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("2014j.....", "*******");

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. Will do some tests later.

Comment: It's running smooth now but i didn't see any email inboxed therein (("receipentemailid")).